# Вопрос по области видимости переменных в Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, global-variables

1) Есть функция в которой есть проверка на существование txt файла. Если он есть то программа открывает его  (при помощи with),  считывает содержание строки (в файле 1 строка) и записывает в переменную nomber. а если нет такого файла то создаёт его и вписывает туда определённое заранее значение (например '0' (str(0))) и записывает этот '0' в переменную  nomber. В return функции указан number (return number)

2) Во второй функции задаётся число (sum) которое нужно прибавить к существующему (полученному из файла и записанному в переменную number) и нужно записать в переменную plus сумму уже полученную при сложении. Но при plus = int(sum) + int(number) пишет что number локальная переменная а если перед этим сделать её глобальной то тоже error.

Как сложить return 1 функции и число из 2 функции чтобы это было return-ом 2 функции?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, **конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе**.

Comment: И полный текст ошибки добавьте.

Comment: @adwawd2edgsef может, у вас файл пустой...

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была связана с предварительным созданием файла txt без содержания текста в заданной директории.